# ActiveMQ one producer multi consumer

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I want to write an application using Active MQ as Queue with One producer many consumers.
I found http://activemq.apache.org/multiple-consumers-on-a-queue.html 
that it can be done with creating session but that doesnt provide any example.Can anyone provide me an example of how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Using multiple consumers (and multiple producers) is the same code as one producer and one consumer. The difference is how many you create/have at once.

Comment: @PeterLawrey so u mean if i just create more receivers then its enough. But then which consumer will receive the message? Because i just want to create one queue and different users fetching messages from it.I have a MDB for receiving the message.

Comment: The next free consumer gets the message. The strategy of how this is done is tune-able but is something you rarely have to change.

Comment: So suppose i want two consumers then I create two Message Driven Beans (MDB1, MDB2) and one Producer for sending the messages. In producer code I can create two sessions that will work. Number of sessions are equal to number of consumers??

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is the functionality of a Topic, why not use that? 
Check out: http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html

Comment: There are legitimate reasons for having more than one consumer on a queue. Specifically, load balancing or redundancy.

Comment: @Michael Agreed. But Jeena's comments let me to believe a topic was what she needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a topic and durable subscribers.  A topic will normally deliver the message to the first consumer dequeuing, but if durable subscribers have subscribed to the topic, messages will be delivered to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2EE/ThisexampleisasimpleJMSclientapplication.htm